# How Can I get http request/response in a java class from a reverse proxy?

Tags: java, tomcat, firewall, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am goning to build a java class which gets the http request or response, by an algorithm tries to find some strings in them, log them and forwards the response to the client.

so, I need a reverse proxy to fetch the request, but
First, I don't know which webservers such s apache (mod_proxy), tomcat, etc can act as a reverse proxy which has the api for java?
Second, I don't know how to get the data from reverse proxy in java class?

Comment: "so, I need a reverse proxy" <- No you don't. Why would you think that?

Comment: It is entirely possible to make http requests and handle the response directly within Core Java to start see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html or to use one of several libraries to aid you. these include but are by no means limited to Apache : http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/, Restlet http://restlet.com/.